# Android adapter with custom row, communicate back to activity list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have an activity with a listview.

At the bottom of the `listview` I have a 'Selected item' `textview` and a save button.
the list view uses an adapter with multiple text fields and a radio button.
I understand how to add click events for the radio buttons in the adapter.
I need to know how to get the click events in the adapter to update the 'Selected item' in the `textview`.

### Edit 9/19

Code Added

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    PlanListObj pl = planAdapter.getItem(position);
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton1:
    selection.setText("Radio: " + pl.getPlanName());
    break;
        default:
    selection.setText("Row: " + pl.getPlanName());
    }
     }
});
```

If I click the radio button on the custom row the `R.id.radioButton1` case is not valid, presumably as the radio button is sending an `onClick`, not an `OnItemClick`.

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Source code is kind of a mess at the moment, with many different (failed) routines commented out.  Will try again tonight based on the answers below.  If not success I'll post the code, at least as it looks.  Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

First I hope you start accepting answers :)

This is simple because you can use in your main activity:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //here you can update the textview and get the selected value from the view or position
    }
});
```

Comment: In onItemClick I know using the position I can determine the row that was clicked. Can I the view to determine whether the radio button was checked.  Sorry about the answers thingy, as you can tell from my points not a frequent question asker more often I'm not the first with the problem (or at least I can find the answer before I ask)

Comment: yes i said in comment you can use the position and view like this: `CheckBox cb = view.findViewById(R.id.yourcheckbox); cb.isChecked()`

Comment: Almost, I can check the radio button but this in itself does not call the OnItemClickListener.  When I touch the row (after turning on the radio) then I can see if the radio button is checked or not.  Think along the lines of wanting two actions to happen, the Radio button should update the message, the row should do something else.

Comment: well you should find the combination you want of OnItemClickListener for the listview and OnCheckedChangeListener for the checkbox and maybe you could use some functions you create inside the adapter. Use a combination.. Maybe in the onCheckedChanged of the checkbox you can call a function you create in the adapter.